# Does every object in a dojo store need to have the same structure?

Tags: dojo

For example take the following

```
require(["dojo/store/Memory",
"dojo/ready"],

function (Memory, ready) {
ready(function () {

//Creating array of data set
 var employees = [{
 name: "Krishna",
 topic: "Sales"
 }, {
 name: "Mohhamad",
 topic: "Sales"
 }, {
 name: "Sanaulla",
 topic: "Marketing"
 }, {
 name: "Raja",
 topic: "Marketing"
 }];

//Creating object store from the array
 var employeeStore = new dojo.store.Memory({
 data: employees,
 idProperty: "name"
 });

//Adding new data to the object store directly
 employeeStore.add({
 name: "Manisha",
 topic: "Advertising"
 });
```

Can I then add an employee to the store with the following items? ( in this case the employee has a new property called salary that was not present when first creating  the store)

```
//Adding new data to the object store directly
 employeeStore.add({
 name: "Manisha",
 topic: "Advertising",
 salary: "5"
 });
```

When I create the Memory Store, does every single object in the store need to follow the original object structure that was set on the data property?

Answer (score 1):

You can add objects with any "structure/property" in a Memory Store.

Below and example, if you inspect and look at `data` property of your store you can see all objects being added.

Off course when using retrieving your objects from the store you need to take care about different structure of your object.

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/6zygkhnf/

```
    require(['dojo/store/Memory'], function(Memory) {
  //Creating array of data set
  var employees = [{
    name: "Krishna",
    topic: "Sales"
  }, {
    name: "Mohhamad",
    topic: "Sales"
  }, {
    name: "Sanaulla",
    topic: "Marketing"
  }, {
    name: "Raja",
    topic: "Marketing"
  }];

  //Creating object store from the array
  var employeeStore = new dojo.store.Memory({
    data: employees,
    idProperty: "name"
  });

  //Adding new data to the object store directly
  employeeStore.add({
    name: "Manisha",
    topic: "Advertising"
  });
  employeeStore.add({
    name: "Manisha2",
    topic: "Advertising2",
    salary: "5"
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is for a new object with different structure that is added, if it doesn't have the idProperty that was specified on creation of the store, the idProperty will get added to the new object automatically.  All other properties don't matter, they can be different from object to object.  All objects in the store will have the idProperty even if new objects don't have it prior to being added to the store.

Example

```
var employees = [{
    name: "Krishna",
    topic: "Sales"
}, {
    name: "Mohhamad",
    topic: "Sales"
}];

var testStore = new Memory({
    data: employees,
    idProperty: "name"
});

//Add a new employee object
testStore.add({ name: "blah", topic: "test1" });

//Add a new object with different properties
testStore.add({ something: "s1", other: "o1" });
```

The store will contain the following, see the last object has different properties and no name property, but the name property was still added to it.

[image]